# c++: can't solve vector subscription error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector

I am trying to take the sum of all the variables in `hours` by iterating through my vector. Now I get this vector subscription error and I don't know how to solve it. Here's my code:

```
int hulpInt = hours[0];

for (int i = hours[1]; i != hours[hours.size()-1]; i++)
{
    hulpInt = hulpInt + i;
}

int HOUR = hulpInt + hours[hours.size()];
```

If you need more code, just comment.

Comment: You might be interested in `std::accumulate`.

Comment: It's an algorithm meant for summing up the values in a container, such as a vector. You can also do other things, like multiply them all instead.

Comment: It's a good idea to include the error in your question.

Comment: In your last line of code `hours[hours.size()]` uses an invalid array index. If `size()` is `x` then the valid indices are 0..x-1.

Comment: @Blastfurnace thanks, now I know why I was wrong. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get an error it's a good idea to include that as well.

Specifically I'm guessing you are indexing out of bounds with `hours[hours.size()]` because vectors are zero based indexes.

STL containers have nifty iterators that help with staying in bounds:

```
int h[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
std::vector<int> hours(h, h+12);
int total(0);
for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator i(hours.begin()); i != hours.end(); ++i)
    total += *i;
```

STL also has algorithms that use these iterators to do common things for you:

```
#include <numeric>

int h[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
std::vector<int> hours(h, h+12);
int total = std::accumulate(hours.begin(), hours.end(), 0);
```

Of course you can also roll your own loops:

```
int h[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
std::vector<int> hours(h, h+12);
int total(0);
for (int i(0); i < int(hours.size()); ++i)
    total += hours[i];
```

All of the above come up with the same result for total they just go about it slightly different ways. There is always more than one way to skin a cat as they say.

Comment: You gave me the best answer, thanks for that! Glad I learned something today.

Answer (score 4):

Two ways of solving this one.

```
#include <functional>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
```

Method 1: Using vector.size()

```
int hulpInt =0;
for(int i=0;i<hours.size();i++){
    hulpInt+= hours[i];
}
```

Method 2 : Using std::accumulate

```
int hulpInt = std::accumulate(hours.begin(),hours.end(),0);
```

Answer (score 3):

See [this documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

You should do something like this:

```
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < hours.size(); ++i) {
    sum += hours[i];
}
```